# How do I get my .emacs init files to load correctly with emacs server?

Tags: emacs, emacsclient

My init files are set up such that my `.emacs` file is a symlink pointing to an OS-specific init that in turn loads the main init file with configs that are unaffected by OS. I've had no problems with this setup for non-server emacs.

However, it does not work right when using emacsclient. For example, I have a setting for `org-mode` so that in Terminal on OSX, `S-Tab` is mapped to backtab so that it works correctly instead of throwing an error about undefined key. This setting works fine if I'm not using emacs server. When I'm using emacsclient, I get the error of undefined keybinding.

I know all my init files are getting loaded without error because any (message "whatever") lines I put in the files show fine when the server is started. So it's not like the emacs server is missing the files somehow. It's as if the mapped keys get loaded for the server but forgotten when a client connects in. I've even tried `eval` of the key mappings once in an emacsclient buffer, but while no errors, no change. Any ideas?

(btw, `--debug-init` doesn't show anything strange. Everything is loading without error.)

Comment: Can you create a minimal init.el that illustrates the problem? (Let's ignore the symlinking and the loading of the OS-neutral init file for now.)

Comment: One possibility is that if you set up keybindings in the init depending on the value of `window-system` or something like that, then the settings may not be for a terminal but GUI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your problem is that your .emacs file sets something like `local-function-key-map` or `input-decode-map` but these variables are terminal-local, which means that every "terminal" (your GUI is one "terminal", and every emacsclient connection over a text-teminal will be another "terminal") gets a different value of this variable.

So you need to re-run that code for every new terminal.  You can do that from `after-make-frame-functions` as suggested by reza.safiyat, tho it will be run more often than needed (once per frame, rather than once per terminal).  But since this is probably only needed for "xterm" terminals, another good option is to do it from `terminal-init-xterm-hook`:

```
(defun my-text-terminal-keys ()
  (define-key input-decode-map ...)
  (define-key local-function-key-map ...))
(add-hook 'terminal-init-xterm-hook #'my-text-terminal-keys)
```

BTW, sometimes an alternative is to use `function-key-map`, since that's a global variable and applies equally to all terminals.

Comment: Interestingly, that hook doesn't seem to be defined anywhere…

Comment: `grep terminal-init-xterm-hook  **/*.el` shows it's in `lisp/term/xterm.el`.  Notice that hooks don't need to be "defined" (an unbound value works just as well as a nil value).

Answer (score 2):

Finally found a solution.

This is a copied solution but sadly I lost the link to it.
Just add this to your `init` file.

```
(defun startup_func(_)
  (load-file "/path/to/custom-keybindings.el"))

(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions #'startup_func)
```